# Мерцает шрифт при смене слайда

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap, carousel

Не могу найти ошибку. При смене слайда в слайдере на странице:
http://www.happy-club.ru/
в футере мерцает шрифт. Отключение пользовательских шрифтов проблему не решило.

https://yadi.sk/i/da8OYv3M3UbzRQ

Comment: А в каком браузере / ОС? Chrome/Mac — всё корректно

Comment: Win 8, все браузеры, которые есть: хром, яндекс, ие

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 - также мерцание

Comment: На win 7 и маке - все в порядке. Может, есть связь

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос гифку с мерцанием. С помощью https://gyazo.com/ можно записать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я столкнулся с этой проблемой уже очень давно и все что я понял это обычный баг или лаг браузеров, точнее того как они обрабатывают анимации. Ответа я не нашел поэтому начал экспериментировать...

В общем единственное решение которое хоть как-то помогает:

Вставляете бесконечную анимацию на элемент внутри проблемного блока. Например такую:

```
.элмент_внутри_проблемного_блока {
animation: crutch  2s infinite;
}

@keyframes crutch {
from {
  transform: scale(1);
  }
to {
  transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Конкретно на вашем сайте я протестировал данный метод на данном селекторе:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    max-width: 96%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    animation: crutch 2s infinite;
}
```

Анимация визуально ничего не меняет, она просто работает бесконечно, тем самым она бесконечно держит глюченый элемент в его нестабильном состоянии. Это костыль конечно, я его так и назвал в примере, но другого решения пока не находил.

Как было:
https://gyazo.com/7aaf8427b01ee0fdf5e6694b51183320

*Смотрим на текст внизу*

Как стало:
https://gyazo.com/a6ba6ca02a5f75607f527e038e3c34ed

Как видите текст все время находиться в слегка размазанном состоянии, но вроде не критично.